# computing the math formula on the mask (google earth engine)

Tags: mask, google-earth-engine, computation

I am about to calculate Chorophyll-a in the water bodies in one region, as I outlined above. I have created a mask, with water=1, land=0(transparent）. And I want to calculate quality formula (NDCI, refer to normalized difference chl-a index) over the mask I created in the last step. Here are my code.

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
       var qa = image.select('QA60')
        var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
        var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
 var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
         qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
 return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .select("B.*")
  .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
   }

  var tiles = ['29UNV']
   var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
   .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
   .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles))
   print(collection)
   var minmin = collection.map(maskS2clouds)
   print(minmin)
    var calndwi = function(image){
     //water mask
     var NDWI = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
     return image.addBands(NDWI).updateMask(NDWI.gt(0));
    };
   print(minmin.map(calndwi));
  //Add NDWI to the clipped image collection
   var withNDWI = minmin.map(calndwi).select('NDWI');
   print("NDWI collection", withNDWI);
  var bb = withNDWI.first();
  Map.addLayer(bb,{},'ss');
   var addNDCI = function(image) {
  var ndci = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDCI');
    return image.addBands(ndci);
   };
   var withNDCI = minmin.map(addNDCI).select('NDCI');
   print("NDCI collection", withNDCI);
   var MASK = function(image) {
  var mask = bb.mask(image);
     return image.addBands(mask);
   };
  var maskk = withNDCI.map(MASK).select('mask');
  print(maskk)**
```

and it give me the bug like ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=20200106T114451_20200106T114531_T29UNV):Image.select: Pattern 'mask' did not match any bands.what should I do? thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `maskk` object does not contain any bands named `mask`, because your `MASK` function does not create or add any bands with that name.

What your code does, as you've currently written it, is this:

```
   var MASK = function(image) {
  // Apply a mask over the 'bb' image.
  var mask = bb.mask(image);
     // return 'image' (which was the 'mask' parameter above), 
     // with ALL bands from the object 'mask', which is now a 'masked' version of bb. 
     // since mask = bb.mask(image), all the bands from bb will be added. 
     return image.addBands(mask);
   };

var maskk = withNDCI
  // Map the 'MASK' function over the 'withNDCI' collection
  .map(MASK)
  // Attempt to select a band named 'mask' (which does not exist).
  .select('mask');
```

I'm not sure what you're looking for when you try to select the mask 'band' - I assume what you want is the masked NCDI image. That's essentially what you have already - but the band names of the `'maskk'` object are `"NDWI"` and `"NDCI"`, since it is derived from the `bb`, and those are the bands that `bb` contains. There is no band named `"mask"`.

Comment: Hi, I just want to get the information only from water (that's way I calculated NDWI before),and calculated NDCI from image collection (with my criteria set before, cloud coverage<20%, and there are 14 images in the year of 2020 for Sentinel) only on the water pixels (water mask I created from last step with NDWI). Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe it's not right for me to use 'mask'? I have checked earth engine catalog before, image1.mask(image2), any pixels in image2 with value=0 will also be set transparent, I just don't know which approach should I use.

Comment: Ah, I see what is happening. You are trying to mask your NCDI image with an image that's *clipped to the extent of water*. What you need is a *mask that covers the whole ROI, with 1s over water and 0s over land.* The fix is in the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc7c3bd8420c4dfd7d4f6d3a0d19da59

Comment: Hi thanks a lot and it works! I have one more question with your answer---the 'mask' function                   as outlined in GEE catalog, mask is 'The mask of an image is set using a call like image1.mask(image2). This call takes the values of image2 and makes them the mask of image1. ((Any pixels in image2 that have the value 0 will be made transparent in image1 )).'                 so if i mask ndci with the water area--'bb.mask(ndci)', ndci is the image2 as describe in GEE catalog, will it made the pixels in NDCI with the value of 0 becomes transparent? Thank you.

Comment: If you run ```bb.mask(ndci)```, the function will return a masked version of ```bb``` (i.e. the ```bb``` image, but transparent in all the areas where ```ndci``` is 0).  </br> If you run ```ndci.mask(bb)```, the function will return a masked version of ```ndci``` (in other words, the ```ndci``` image, but transparent in all the areas where ``bb`` is 0. If you just want ```ndci``` in the areas where ```ndci``` is greater than zero (in other words, ```ndci``` masked by itself), you can try ```ndci.mask(ndci.gt(0))``` - I think that should do it.